# My website is getting a lot of unknown traffic which is inturn consuming many GB's of bandwidth

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, bandwidth

I have a wordpress site hosted which is experiencing some kind of attack. My hosting stats show that my account has consumed 4GB of bandwidth in just 20 days. After some digging I found out that there have been more than 15,000 visits to my website in just few weeks. I checked my logs and found a pattern of GET requests. Thousands of IP's are making a GET request on following url's

1) /using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/registration-form.html?layout=complete

2) /using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/login-form.html

3) /?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit

4) /europe-tours/item/23-praesent-viverra-nisl-eu-enim-mollis-interdum.html

None of these URL's exist on my website.

I also installed a security plugin which shows my website as a referer to all these url's. I have no idea what is going on, so some help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Best way to restrict frequent IP who visited you sites more than 1000 or more time in a day.

Comment: this is not ddos, 15K visits over few weeks, hardly qualifies

Comment: @AlexAndrei my bad .. updated my comment and I had not seen timing of weeks in question... and thanks to point this thing :).

Comment: I removed that comment as it wasn't written very well. What I was trying to say was that ddos is hardly used over http since other methods work better for the purpose. see amplification factor, here http://www.christian-rossow.de/articles/Amplification_DDoS.php

Answer (score 2):

Your domain is just scanned for known vulnerabilities.
The server will usually respond with a `404` and the bot should give up.

Such traffic shouldn't consume too much bandwidth, since the bot would either send a `HEAD` or simply a `GET` to that url.
It all depends on how heavy your `404` response is.

If you don't want to receive visits from these IP addresses anymore simply block the requests either at web server level or at network interface level.

You can do a simple test to see the size in bytes of one of those requests and then see if this is the real cause of your 4GB spike in bandwidth usage.

In a terminal run `curl` with `-s` (silent), `-o` write the output to `/dev/null` and print out the `size_download` variable.

```
curl -so /dev/null http://yourdomain.com/europe-tours/item/23-praesent-viverra-nisl-eu-enim-mollis-interdum.html -w '%{size_download}'
```

Should give you a value, which is the size in `bytes` of your `404` page.
Multiply by 15000, to get total size in bytes of all the requests.
Transform to GB and compare with the spike.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I checked download size using curl and the estimate is 403MB for 15000 404 requests but there is a major development in the issue. I checked some graphical logs of the website and it shows the attacker is not just hitting 404 error but also other url's (more than 116 url's which include webpages and scripts like js, php, css, txt, png, jpeg etc files) which actually exist on the website.

Comment: Below are the screeshots of some stats:
http://s10.postimg.org/ysoymrqp5/img_1.jpg
http://s10.postimg.org/6h3epq6sp/img_2.jpg
http://s10.postimg.org/6rax92lex/img_3.jpg
http://s10.postimg.org/kjkqqymsp/img_4.jpg

Comment: I can't make anything from the screenshots without digging deeper, but if you have reason to believe that some IP address is generating unwanted traffic, just filter it. Let me know what kind of web server you are using and I can provide some guidance, ex. apache or nginx. Or if you have access to the network configuration you can deny requests in `iptables` at the network interface level.

Comment: just be careful so you don't mistake legitimate traffic, such as search engine bots or even visitors with malicious traffic ending up hurting yourself :)

Comment: Well the scree shots say that 116 different links of website have been accessed with the top link viewed 24,060 times, then next 8,000 times and so on. Also most traffic has been from USA with top IP consuming 902MB of bandwidth. Also 14,675 visitors have visited my website consuming 2.75 GB and bots & worms consuming 443MB of bandwidth.


 I am using Linux, Apache 2.2.26

Comment: the IP address generating most traffic, meaning the most requests, not the most bandwidth, is 62.210.203.128, from France and has used little more over 150MB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96133/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-danish).